# get the Autowired service in filter class

Tags: java, spring-mvc, filter, autowired

there is an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registeredatorg.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:252)at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
```

and my `web.xml` config is declared a `DelegatingFilterProxy`. if a have different auth rule, how can i write in my filter? by those diff url name?

```
public class SecurityFilter implements Filter{
@Autowired
private TokenService tokenService;
@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    String token = request.getParameter("token");//:TODO}}
```

and spring config is:

```
<bean id="securityFilter" class="xx.filter.SecurityFilter"></bean>
```

Comment: your question is not at all clear.

Answer (score 0):

The filter class is not an spring anootated class and hence won't load any of the dependent spring related classes. Ideally if you annotate UserFilter as a spring component then your @autowired dependents will also load.